# Client Side Cookies

Tags: http, cookies

How to enable client side cookie for a page so that when a page is invoked for the first time , it works fine. Bur whe nthe same page is invoked for the second or third time , it gets redirected to other page.
i.e. Only one tab works at a time.
In rest of the other tabs, a default sequence works.

Comment: This is pretty basic stuff. What language are you working in? What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 1):

As we don't know what language you're talking about, I'm going with pseudo code!

```
if cookie 'times' is not set
    set cookie 'times' to 1
else
    set cookie 'times' to (value of cookie 'times' + 1)

if value of cookie 'times' >= 7
    redirect to 'otherpage.html'

show normal stuff
```

Comment: This concept is for a web application. Want the code in client side(using javascript).

Comment: Its occurence:
"I send you  a mail with a link.if u open the link in 1 tab, it plays correctly. But if opened in multiple tabs, it doesnt play correctly"